# How to debug C++ application in docker with VSCode

Tags: c++, linux, docker, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a C++ application running inside a docker container with VSCode. I followed the below-mentioned steps to do that

1. Installed C/C++ and Remote-Containers extension in VSCode
2. Connected VSCode to the docker container
3. Added the below C/C++: (gdb) Attach configuration in launch.json

```
{
      "name": "(gdb) Attach",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "attach",
      "program": "/usr/local/bin/myfeature",
      "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "additionalSOLibSearchPath": "/usr/local/bin/myfeature.dbg",
      "sourceFileMap":{
        "<source-path>": "/usr/local/src/test/av/"
      },
      "setupCommands": [
          {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          }
      ]
}
```

When I start debugging the breakpoints in the file myclass.cc are disabled and show status as "Module containing this breakpoint has not been loaded yet...."

I am not very familiar with gdb but when I run this command from the command line

```
gdb /usr/local/bin/myfeature
```

I get this

```
Reading symbols from /usr/local/bin/myfeature...
Reading symbols from /usr/local/bin/myfeature.dbg...
```

Then I am able to add breakpoint using

```
break myclass.cc:15
```

If gdb is able to read symbols and add breakpoint then why is VSCode not able to do that? What am I doing wrong here?
Thank you

Comment: Did you add -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug to your CMake generation?